# How do I get rid of the gap of color between the footer and my copyright section?

Tags: html, css

I have put down below my `HTML` and `CSS`. I can't figure out why the gap is there and the bottom. I will put a picture in as well.

**My Code :**

```css
/*

Landon Byrd
Fall 2021

    Light Blue  #06aed5
    Darker Blue #086788
    Cream White #f2f4f3
    Yellow      #f0c808
    Rich Red    #dd1c1a 
    Black       #333
*/
/* Global Settings */
h1 {text-align: center}
h2 {text-align: center; color: #086788;}
h3 {text-align: center; color: #086788; text-decoration: underline #f2f4f3; text-shadow: 2px 2px #f2f4f3;}
.wrapper{width:85%; margin:0 auto; max-width: 960px; }

/* Nav Section */
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #f0c808;
  color: white;
}

/* Centered section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Right-aligned section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

/* Responsive navigation menu - display links on top of each other instead of next to each other (for mobile devices) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .topnav-right {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .topnav-centered a {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
  }
}

/* Main Section */
.banner{justify-content: center;background-color: #333; border-radius: 2pt; color: #f2f4f3; border-radius: 5%;}
.name{font-weight: bold; color: #f0c808}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.img1 {float:left; width: 300px; height: 350px; margin:15px; border-radius: 20%;}
.img2 {float: right; width: 330px; height: 350px; border-radius: 20%;}


body {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpg"); 
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 16px
}



/* Footer Section */
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.footer{text-align: center; background-color: #333; color: #f2f4f3; }
.box{float:left; width: 33.33%;}
.footer::after{content: ""; clear:both; display:table;}

/* copyright section */
.copyright {text-align: center; background-color: #333; color: #f2f4f3; }

/* Menu */
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

.menu {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu-group-heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.menu-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 1.5em;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.menu-item-text {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu-item-heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-item-name {
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.menu-item-description {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .menu {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .menu-group {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .menu-item-image {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>SuperRestraunt</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>

<!-- Top navigation -->
<div class="topnav">

  <!-- Centered link -->
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Left-aligned links (default) -->
  <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

  <!-- Right-aligned links -->
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a href="#search">Search</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>

</div>

    <main class="wrapper">
    
        <div class="banner">
            <h1><span class="name">SuperRestraunt</span></h1>
            <h2>Serving the best food in Macon since 2015.</h2>
            <h3>Coupons and Weekly Advertisement.</h3>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/coupon1.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/coupon2.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column"></div>
            
            <img class="img1" src="images/burger.jpg" alt="burger">
            
            <div class="column"></div>
            
            <p> Are you looking for the best southern cooking in all of middle Georgia? If so, you have looked in the right place!</p>
            
            <p> Our chefs have over 30 years in combined experience</p>
            
            <h2>About the Owner</h2>
            
            <img class="img2" src="images/chef.jpg" alt="chef">
            
            <p>Executive chef Nicholas St. Clair knew he wanted to do something extraordinary from a young age. Little did he know, his budding culinary expertise would launch him into a whirlwind adventure in the fine dining industry. St. Clair, who graduated with high honors from the California Culinary Institute in Pasadena, CA, polished his cuisine with some of America’s premier chefs over the past five years. St. Clair and his wife, Alison, ventured into the restaurant business with determination for success and passion for fine cuisine. e took a blind leap of faith and opened a place of his own.</p>
            
        </div>
    
        <h2><em>Contact us for a reservations</em></h2>
        <p>Please call at least 2 days ahead for all reservations that include 10 or more people.</p>


    </main>
    
  <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="box">
            <p>SuperRestraunt</p>
            <p>(478) 302-1981</p>
            <p>manager@superrestraunt.com</p>
            <p>Contact us via Skype by clicking the following link</p>
            <a href="skype:echo123?call">
            Call Us Today!
            </a>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Check out are Social Media for more coupons and pictures!</p>
            <p>Facebook:</p>
            <p>Instagram:</p>
            <p>Twitter:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Locations:</p>
            <br/>
            <p>543 Cherry St suite b, Macon, GA 31201</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <div class="copyright">
        <h2>@copyright: Landon Byrd</h2>
        <p>Fall 2021, All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
    
<p>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>
</p>

<a href="#top">Back to top of page</a>              
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I am also wondering how to change the hyperlink text color that is in my footer, as well as changing the back to top into a button. Thanks for the help! If needed I can post separate questions for those though.

Comment: Open developers tools and inspect the elements with gap and check what causes this gap appearance.

Comment: Whenever you start any project, there are few default CSS properties that you need to get rid of. Go ahead and write `* {margin: 0px; pading: 0px; }` on the top of your CSS file and see if this gets rid of the space. This will probably mess up a lot of other things as well which is why you should have done this at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

###### To Change the color of hyperlink `Back to top of page` in footer and put it into a button.

Simply you can use this code snippet to change the font color of hyperlink and keep it into a button.

```css
/* Footer Section */
.footer .top_a{
  color : Red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>SuperRestraunt</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>

<footer class = 'footer'>

<button class = 'top_btn'> <a href="#top" class = 'top_a'>Back to top of page</a> </button>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to make the button more nicely just add this `CSS` part to your `CSS` file.

```css
/* Footer Section */
.footer .top_btn{
  background : #1f1f1f;
  border : none;
  border-radius : 5px;
  width : 200px;
  height : 50px;
}

.footer .top_a{
  color : #efefef;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>SuperRestraunt</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>

<footer class = 'footer'>

<button class = 'top_btn'> <a href="#top" class = 'top_a'>Back to top of the page</a> </button>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```